# wildcard cts:element-value-query returning wrong matches

Tags: marklogic

`wildcard` `cts:element-value-query` is not behaving as expected.

insert doc query:

```
xdmp:document-insert('/sample/2.xml', <data>the living Theater</data>)
```

cts query:

```
cts:search(
    doc(),
    cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('data'), 'theater* *', ('wildcarded', 'case-insensitive', 'unstemmed', 'punctuation-sensitive', 'whitespace-sensitive')),
    'unfiltered'
)
```

Above cts query is returning me the `/sample/2.xml` document. As per my understanding this query should not return the  above document it should return only the docs starting with `theater` text.

seems like the issue is with the below text pattern.

present text in document : `@@@ word @@@text`

search term: `@@@t* *`

@ - can be any character.

I am able to reproduce the problem with the below data as well.

present text in doc: `mark the marklogic`

search text: `markl* *`

wildcard related indexes are set to true.

I have pasted the database configuration, it might help in finding the problem.

**Database configuration:**

```
<package-database xmlns="http://marklogic.com/manage/package/databases">
    <config>
        <name>publishers</name>
        <package-database-properties>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <retired-forest-count>0</retired-forest-count>
            <language>en</language>
            <stemmed-searches>advanced</stemmed-searches>
            <word-searches>true</word-searches>
            <word-positions>true</word-positions>
            <fast-phrase-searches>true</fast-phrase-searches>
            <fast-reverse-searches>false</fast-reverse-searches>
            <triple-index>true</triple-index>
            <triple-positions>true</triple-positions>
            <fast-case-sensitive-searches>true</fast-case-sensitive-searches>
            <fast-diacritic-sensitive-searches>true</fast-diacritic-sensitive-searches>
            <fast-element-word-searches>true</fast-element-word-searches>
            <element-word-positions>true</element-word-positions>
            <fast-element-phrase-searches>true</fast-element-phrase-searches>
            <element-value-positions>true</element-value-positions>
            <attribute-value-positions>true</attribute-value-positions>
            <field-value-searches>true</field-value-searches>
            <field-value-positions>true</field-value-positions>
            <three-character-searches>true</three-character-searches>
            <three-character-word-positions>true</three-character-word-positions>
            <fast-element-character-searches>true</fast-element-character-searches>
            <trailing-wildcard-searches>true</trailing-wildcard-searches>
            <trailing-wildcard-word-positions>true</trailing-wildcard-word-positions>
            <fast-element-trailing-wildcard-searches>true</fast-element-trailing-wildcard-searches>
            <word-lexicons>
                <word-lexicon>http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint</word-lexicon>
            </word-lexicons>
            <two-character-searches>false</two-character-searches>
            <one-character-searches>false</one-character-searches>
            <uri-lexicon>true</uri-lexicon>
            <collection-lexicon>true</collection-lexicon>
            <reindexer-enable>true</reindexer-enable>
            <reindexer-throttle>5</reindexer-throttle>
            <reindexer-timestamp>0</reindexer-timestamp>
            <directory-creation>manual</directory-creation>
            <maintain-last-modified>false</maintain-last-modified>
            <maintain-directory-last-modified>false</maintain-directory-last-modified>
            <inherit-permissions>false</inherit-permissions>
            <inherit-collections>false</inherit-collections>
            <inherit-quality>false</inherit-quality>
            <in-memory-limit>174080</in-memory-limit>
            <in-memory-list-size>341</in-memory-list-size>
            <in-memory-tree-size>85</in-memory-tree-size>
            <in-memory-range-index-size>11</in-memory-range-index-size>
            <in-memory-reverse-index-size>11</in-memory-reverse-index-size>
            <in-memory-triple-index-size>44</in-memory-triple-index-size>
            <large-size-threshold>1024</large-size-threshold>
            <locking>fast</locking>
            <journaling>fast</journaling>
            <journal-size>682</journal-size>
            <journal-count>2</journal-count>
            <preallocate-journals>false</preallocate-journals>
            <preload-mapped-data>false</preload-mapped-data>
            <preload-replica-mapped-data>false</preload-replica-mapped-data>
            <range-index-optimize>facet-time</range-index-optimize>
            <positions-list-max-size>256</positions-list-max-size>
            <format-compatibility>automatic</format-compatibility>
            <index-detection>automatic</index-detection>
            <expunge-locks>none</expunge-locks>
            <tf-normalization>scaled-log</tf-normalization>
            <merge-priority>lower</merge-priority>
            <merge-max-size>32768</merge-max-size>
            <merge-min-size>1024</merge-min-size>
            <merge-min-ratio>2</merge-min-ratio>
            <merge-timestamp>0</merge-timestamp>
            <retain-until-backup>false</retain-until-backup>
            <assignment-policy-name>bucket</assignment-policy-name>
        </package-database-properties>
    </config>
</package-database>
```

Comment: Do you get the correct results when the search is executed with the `'filtered'` option?

Comment: @MadsHansen Yes.. with filtered I am getting the right results, But I can't use filtered option because of it's slowness.

Comment: Try enabling element word positions. You need that to accurately resolve multi-token values without filtering..

Comment: @grtjn `element word position` is set to true. Still the same problem. Tried adding the word lexicon with `http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint` collation but no gain.

Comment: Hmm, I think I should have said `element value positions`. Is that enabled?

Comment: `element value position` is also set to true

Comment: @grtjn please let me know in case you want to see the `xdmp:plan` output of the above cts query.

Comment: Please help as I am facing this issue a lot, not able to identify what wrong I am doing. It looks like `value` query is behaving as `word` query

Answer (score 2):

Having a unfiltered search comes with some [caveats](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/unfiltered#id_89797):

> - They determine the results directly from the indexes, **without filtering for validation**. This makes unfiltered results most 
>     comparable to traditional search-engine style results.
> - **They include    false-positive results**. False-positive results can originate from a    number of situations, including phrase searches
>     containing 3 or more    words, **certain wildcard searches**,
>     punctuation-sensitive,    diacritic-sensitive, and/or case-sensitive
>     searches.

MarkLogic provides a way to determine if a result is a false-positive. You can use `cts:contains` for that. This xquery shows that your result is indeed a false positive:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare boundary-space preserve;
declare namespace qm="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/query-meters";

let $trueCounter := 0
let $falseCounter := 0
let $query := cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('data'), 'theater* *')
let $x := 
  for $result in cts:search(fn:doc(), $query, "unfiltered")
  return
  (
  if ( cts:contains($result, $query) )
  then ( xdmp:set($trueCounter, $trueCounter + 1) )
  else ( xdmp:set($falseCounter, $falseCounter + 1) )
  )
return
<results>
  <resultTotal>{$trueCounter}</resultTotal>
  <false-positiveTotal>{$falseCounter}</false-positiveTotal>
  <elapsed-time>{xdmp:query-meters()/qm:elapsed-time/text()}
  </elapsed-time>
</results>
```

MarkLogic searches are split into two steps:

1. Candidate id resolution. ML searches for matching documents from the index. These are only candidates, meaning they might be false positives. This is useful for narrowing down documents, so it does not have to load too many fragments.
2. Candidate id are used to load fragments from disk. Each Fragment will then be again tested against the initial query. This step filters false-positives.

By using a unfiltered query, you do not have the second step and thereby false-positives. You can read more about that [here](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/unfiltered#id_13165).

Edit:
[This](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/unfiltered#id_74746) section further describes applications which can use unfiltered searches:

> - Your content and search terms are such that you know the unfiltered searches are also accurate (for example, the searches are all
>     performed at document or **fragment roots**, they are **single-term queries**,
>     and are **not wildcard, punctuation-sensitive, diacritic-sensitive,**
>     **and/or capitalization-sensitive searches**).
> - You do not mind if there are some false-positive results because the results are an estimate (that is, they need to be fast, but are
>     not required to be exact).
> - Your searches return a large number of results and you want efficient ways to jump to a particular portion of those results.

As item one states, you cannot use wildcard queries if you do not want false-positives. I guess you should stick to filtered searches then.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an element range index on data element and then run the below search:

```
let $terms :=  cts:element-value-match(xs:QName("data"),"theater* *")
return
  cts:search(
    doc(),
    cts:element-value-query(
      xs:QName('data'), 
      $terms, 
      ('wildcarded', 'case-insensitive', 'unstemmed', 'punctuation-sensitive', 'whitespace-sensitive')
    ),
    'unfiltered'
  )
```

This will not fetch you '/sample/2.xml' document

Comment: it is a good work around but I am curious to know why `cts:element-value-query` is not working as expected, why it's failing in the above mentioned case?
Hitting database two times will also impact the performance, especially when the `cts:element-value-match` will match great number of values.